# JavaScript seems not to be running any further than first few lines?

Tags: javascript, html, if-statement

I am running some of my code on a web server that should generate the HTML code for a phrase and an action of a button, but the code does not seem to run any further than the first three lines. I used a console.log() function to figure it out, so it prints the two variables but does not seem to go any further.

```js
function generate() {
  phrase = document.getElementById("phrase").value;
  action = document.getElementById("action").value;
  console.log(phrase + action);
  if (action == "alertphrase") {
    var htaction = 'alert(phrase);';
    return htaction;
  }
  if (action == "play-sound") {
    var htaction = 'var x = document.getElementById("audio-el"); \n x.play();';
    return htaction;
  }
  if (action == "image") {
    var htaction = 'var x = document.getElementById("img-el"); \n x.src = "image.jpg"';
    return htaction;
  }
  var htresult = '<!DOCTYPE html>\n<html>\n<head><title>HTML and JavaScript phrase</title></head>\n<body>\n<h3>' + phrase + '</h3>\n<button onclick="action()">Do something</button>\n<script>\nfunction action() {\n' + action + '\n}\n</script>\n</body>\n</html>';
  console.log(htaction);
  console.log(htresult);
  document.writeln(htresult);
}
```

```html
<p id="heading">HTML text generator</p>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<p>Enter a phrase and select an action for a button and click "Generate", to see the HTML code for your phrase and button.</p>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<p>Type a phrase:</p>
<input id="phrase" type="text"><br>
<p>Select an action for button:</p>
<select id="action">
  <option value="alertphrase">Alert phrase</option>
  <option value="play-sound">Play sound</option>
  <option value="image">Display an image</option>
</select>
<br>
<button onclick="generate()">Generate</button>
<p id="htresult"></p>
```

Comment: You're returning inside the if blocks. Return stops the code immediately.

Comment: Thank you so much, that worked! And thanks for the quick reply

Comment: What should I do instead of the return statements though?

Comment: What were you using the return statements for in the first place? You're not using any return values. Just declare `var htaction` outside of the conditional blocks, set the values inside the conditional blocks, and you're good to go.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I replaced your "/" with "\/"  in your `htresult` variable because you have to escape the "/". I also took out your returns in your if statement and made `htaction` a global variable in your `generate` function. Hopefully this helps:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="font.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <title>HTML text generator</title>
</head>
<body>
  <script src="js/generate.js"></script>
  <p id="heading">HTML text generator</p>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <p>Enter a phrase and select an action for a button and click "Generate", to see the HTML code for your phrase and button.</p>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <p>Type a phrase:</p>
  <input id="phrase" type="text"><br>
  <p>Select an action for button:</p>
  <select id="action">
    <option value="alertphrase">Alert phrase</option>
    <option value="play-sound">Play sound</option>
    <option value="image">Display an image</option>
  </select>
  <br>
  <button onclick="generate()">Generate</button>
  <p id="htresult"></p>
</body>
</html>
<script>
function generate() {
  phrase = document.getElementById("phrase").value;
  action = document.getElementById("action").value;
  var htaction = '';
  console.log(phrase + action);
  if (action == "alertphrase"){
   htaction  = 'alert(phrase);';
  }
  if (action == "play-sound"){
     htaction = 'var x = document.getElementById("audio-el"); \n x.play();';
  }
  if (action == "image"){
     htaction = 'var x = document.getElementById("img-el"); \n x.src = "image.jpg"';
  }
  var htresult = '<!DOCTYPE html>\n<html>\n<head><title>HTML and JavaScript phrase</title></head>\n<body>\n<h3>' + phrase +'</h3>\n<button onclick="action()">Do something</button>\n<script>\nfunction action() {\n' + action + '\n}\n<\/script>\n<\/body>\n<\/html>';
  console.log(htaction);
  console.log(htresult);
  console.log(htresult);
}
</script>
```

Comment: Yes! This worked just as I wanted it to. Thank you also for explaining your answer!